# Same code with PyQT5/PySide2 runs on MacOS but throws an error on Linux

Tags: python, linux, macos, matplotlib, pyqt5

I wrote GUI using PySide2, numpy and matplotlib which works without any problm without problem on MacOS 11.2.3. However I get an error when running the code on Ubuntu 20.4 and The code works

I made a GUI using PySide2 and matplotlib. The goal is click on an image and store the coordinate of the clicks in a csv. After launching the application on Ubuntu and having clicked on the "button" button, I get an error message (provided after the code). It seems that under the Linux, the code is being run until line 91 (although no clicks where made on the image yet and therefore, the dataframe to store them is obviously empty) while on MacOS, the interpreter has stopped at line 76 waiting for the clicks of the user (on MacOS the picture has launched and there is nothing on the terminal)

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QFileDialog
os.environ['QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER'] = '1'



coords_Event = [] 

size_win_x = 10
size_win_y = 7
dpi_val = 100


class GUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        height_btn = 40 
        width_btn = 350
        
        button_position_x = 0
        button_position_y = 20 
        
        button_position_x = button_position_x + 50
        btn2 = QPushButton('Button', self)     
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.Event)
        btn2.resize(width_btn, height_btn + 20)
        btn2.move(button_position_y, button_position_x)       

        self.show()


    def Event(self):
        dir_path = os.getcwd()

        figure = plt.figure(figsize = (size_win_x,size_win_y), dpi=dpi_val) 

        global coords_Event
        coords_Event = []

        def onclick(event):
                ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
                print('x = %d, y = %d'%(
                    ix, iy))
                global coords_Event
                coords_Event.append((ix, iy))
                return coords_Event        
        cid = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

        pixel_array = np.array([[1,2,3], [100,5,6]])
        figure2 = plt.imshow(pixel_array)
        plt.savefig(dir_path + '/raw.png')
        plt.title("the title")
        plt.show()
        
        print("ok1")

        df = pd.DataFrame(coords_Event,
                columns = ['X', 'Y']) 
        string_csv = dir_path + "/coords_Event.csv"

        print("ok2")
        print(string_csv)
        df.to_csv(string_csv, 
        header=True)
        df2 = pd.read_csv(string_csv)  
        print("df2: ", df2)
        print(df2.iloc[0]["X"])
        print(df2.iloc[1]["X"])
        
        print("ok3")
        ic(coords_Event)

        clicked_data = (coords_Event[1][0] - coords_Event[0][0]) 
        df3 = pd.DataFrame ({"clicked_data": [clicked_data]})
        string_csv = dir_path + "/clicked_data.csv"
        print(string_csv)
        df3.to_csv(string_csv, 
        header=True)
        print("ok5")

def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the error message on Ubuntu

```
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
ok1
[]
ok2
/home/user/Documents/myApp/coords_Event.csv
df2:  Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, X, Y]
Index: []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug_05.py", line 92, in Event
    print(df2.iloc[0]["X"])
  File "/home/user/Documents/myApp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 895, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/home/user/Documents/myApp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1501, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "/home/user/Documents/myApp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1444, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

I checked the packages of the environment on Ubuntu and MacOS and they are exactly the same

Here is a piece of code that is maybe more straighforward that outputs the clicked coordinate under linux but not under MacOS:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QFileDialog
os.environ['QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER'] = '1'

coords_Event = [] 

size_win_x = 2
size_win_y = 2
dpi_val = 100

class GUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        height_btn = 40 
        width_btn = 350
        
        button_position_x = 0
        button_position_y = 20 
        
        button_position_x = button_position_x + 50
        btn2 = QPushButton('Button', self)     
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.Event)
        btn2.resize(width_btn, height_btn + 20)
        btn2.move(button_position_y, button_position_x)       

        self.show()

    def Event(self):
        dir_path = os.getcwd()

        def onclick(event):
            global ix, iy
            ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
            print('x = %d, y = %d'%(
                ix, iy))
            global coords_Event
            coords_Event.append((ix, iy))
            return coords_Event        

        fig = plt.figure(figsize = (size_win_x,size_win_y), dpi=dpi_val) 
        pixel_array = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6]])
        fig2 = plt.imshow(pixel_array)
        
        cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

        plt.show()
        print(coords_Event)

def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Looks like coords_Event.csv doesn't have anything in it. This is not a PyQt/PySide issue.

Comment: @justengel: thanks a lot for your comment. I guess you tried the code on linux or just read the question. If so: indeed, the code does not store anything in `coords_Event`. However on MacOS it does and this is the purpose of my question: why the difference and where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running on Windows, and your code has the same problem.

The first thing I noticed was that you do not have a backend specified. On my system clicking the button just shows an image without a GUI. In this situation there is nothing for click events to be connected to, and there is no GUI window to close.

I'm assuming on MacOS a plot figure shows up and lets you click on the graph several times. Once you close the graph `print("ok1")` is run. If this is the case `plt.show()` is blocking and waiting for the window to close. This is really a matplotlib issue. I tried running `plt.show(block=True)` which did not work with PySide2. There could be a PySide2 compatibility issue or a configuration file or the system setting causes different behavior.

The code below does checks if the figure.canvas is visible and blocks until it is closed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QFileDialog
os.environ['QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER'] = '1'

import matplotlib
try:
    matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt5'] = 'PySide2'
except (KeyError, Exception):
    pass
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


coords_Event = []

size_win_x = 10
size_win_y = 7
dpi_val = 100


dir_path = os.getcwd()


class GUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.coords_Event = []
        height_btn = 40
        width_btn = 350

        button_position_x = 0
        button_position_y = 20

        button_position_x = button_position_x + 50
        btn2 = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.Event)
        btn2.resize(width_btn, height_btn + 20)
        btn2.move(button_position_y, button_position_x)

        self.show()

    def save_coord(self, event):
        ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
        print('x = %d, y = %d' % (ix, iy))
        self.coords_Event.append((ix, iy))
        return coords_Event

    def Event(self):
        figure = plt.figure(figsize=(size_win_x, size_win_y), dpi=dpi_val)

        self.coords_Event = []
        cid = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.save_coord)

        pixel_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [100, 5, 6]])
        figure2 = plt.imshow(pixel_array)
        plt.savefig(dir_path + '/raw.png')
        plt.title("the title")

        # Block here until figure is closed.
        plt.show()
        while figure.canvas.isVisible():
            QApplication.processEvents()

        self.finish_coords()

    def finish_coords(self):
        print("ok1")

        df = pd.DataFrame(self.coords_Event, columns = ['X', 'Y'])
        string_csv = dir_path + "/coords_Event.csv"

        print("ok2")
        print(string_csv)
        df.to_csv(string_csv, header=True)
        df2 = pd.read_csv(string_csv)
        print("df2: ", df2)
        print(df2.iloc[0]["X"])
        print(df2.iloc[1]["X"])

        print("ok3")
        # ic(coords_Event)

        clicked_data = (self.coords_Event[1][0] - self.coords_Event[0][0])
        df3 = pd.DataFrame({"clicked_data": [clicked_data]})
        string_csv = dir_path + "/clicked_data.csv"
        print(string_csv)
        df3.to_csv(string_csv, header=True)
        print("ok5")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Many thanks @justengel! I didn't know the "backend" part. Do you have a particular recommendation for literature / documentation on the subject? Many thanks again!