# "event loop is already running" while using the pdb debugger in an application running with matplotlib and PySide2

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside2, pdb

I have an application in which the user has to click on images using matplotlib. I want to use the debugger `pdb` (line 53), however, when I launch the app and click on the button, a message

```
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
```

appears and  prevents me of using the debugger. I suspect that it comes from the following lines but I'm not sure

```
import matplotlib
try:
    matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt5'] = 'PySide2'
except (KeyError, Exception):
    pass
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

I did implement those lines thanks to the answer I got from this question I asked previously:
[Same code with PyQT5/PySide2 runs on MacOS but throws an error on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908037/same-code-with-pyqt5-pyside2-runs-on-macos-but-throws-an-error-on-linux)

How could I retain the same code structure with backend and being able to use the pdb debugger?

```
import sys
import os 
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import matplotlib
import pdb

try:
    matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt5'] = 'PySide2'
except (KeyError, Exception):
    pass
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QFileDialog
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QTextStream

os.environ['QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER'] = '1'


from IPython.core import ultratb
import pdb

sys.excepthook = ultratb.FormattedTB(mode='Verbose', color_scheme='Linux', call_pdb=True)


class GUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        height_btn = 40 
        width_btn = 350
        
        button_position_x = 0
        button_position_y = 20 

        button_position_x = button_position_x = 0
        button_position_y = button_position_y + 400
        btn15 = QPushButton('button', self)     
        btn15.clicked.connect(self.Plotfunction)
        btn15.resize(width_btn, height_btn)
        btn15.move(button_position_y, button_position_x)       
        self.show()

    def Plotfunction(self):
        pdb.set_trace()
        print("ok")


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: try move `PySide2` imports before `matplotlib` imports

Comment: Thanks one more time @eyllanesc! That solved the problem for the script of the question. However in the main application the problems persist. I have to dig further and getting closer to the problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default matplotlib will load the binding (PyQt or PySide2) that is already imported, or if there are none loaded then it will try to import them and the first one that manages to import it will use it. Apparently in the case of the OP it is first importing PyQt causing that problem. The solution is to import PySide2 and then matplotlib so that it prefers PySide2 as the backend binding.